# jQuery - Control a divs scroll using the browsers scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to make only an overflowed div scrollable, even when you try to scroll anywhere on the page, out of the div. I've come across a site before that's done it, but wasn't sure how.

Here's a basic markup to give a better idea what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<html>
    <header>
    </header>

    <style type="text/css">
        html, body, div{ min-height: 100%; }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="side-bar left-col"></div>
                <div class="content-area middle-col"></div> <-- This div will be overflowed.
                <div class="feature-image right-col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you scroll anywhere on the site, instead of the whole site scrolling, only the middle div section will. I don't want to used position:fixed on anything either. Is this possible with jQuery?

**See the Fiddle of how it should work:** http://jsfiddle.net/ks096Lts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery-mousewheel is probably what you are looking for : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

You can target the div that will scroll, wherever your cursor is placed on the page

```
$(function() {
    var $target = $('.main');
    $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      $target.scrollTop($target.scrollTop() - (delta * 30));
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

see here : http://jsfiddle.net/5h47wygo/

Comment: That's exactly what I had needed, thanks for this! 
The job's now passed, but this will be super handy to keep as a future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css for horizontal(x) or vertical(y) scrolling to the middle div:
    style="overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:auto;"

If you want the scroll bars to be visible all the time then change auto to scroll.

Comment: Thanks Gregg - but that's now what I'm trying to do. 
I want to mimmick the browsers scroll - using the browsers scrollbar, not the div's scrollbar to control the content inside the overflowed div. 

Doing it with just CSS means you have to still interact with the actual div / mouse over the actual div before scrolling. I want to be able to do this from anywhere on the site.